# How can I to refactor this code and decouple method?

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, clean-architecture

I have set of entities(templates)

[image]

I need to clone full this set and create same set with new Ids.

I have 3 methods like this(Entity One is User):

```java
private Map<String, String> createUsers() {
    Map<String, String> userIds = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    while (users.hasNext()) {
        User user = users.next();
        String oldId = user.getId();
        user.setId(generateNewId());
        user.setName(generateNewName());
        userService.saveUser(user);
        userIds.put(oldId, user.getId());
    }
    return userIds;
}
```

And two similar methods(Entity two is Person and Entity Three is Book). In each method, I create new entity and store old and new IDS. After that, I clone Orders and relink old id and new id. I do it like this:

```java
if (userIds.containsKey(order.getUserId())) {
    order.setUserId(userIds.get(order.getUserId()));
}

if (personIds.containsKey(order.getPersonId())) {
    order.setPersonId(personIds.get(order.getPersonId()));
}
```

This structure is ugly and I want to refactor it. But I have not ideas.

Comment: This would probably be better fit for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS As it currently stands it's an ill fit for either site.

Comment: I'm confused with your diagram. What is the bottom box representing and what do those lines means? Following the question then there are old id and new id. Then we have order and relink. We have no knowledge on your business requirement. I'm not clear what are you trying to do.